# How to use operator for where filter clause?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i know we can make use of the `where filter` to help get more specific result during running **runmqsc**. i have no problem with those operators like `LT、GT、EQ、NE、LE and GE`. However, as with `LK、NL`, it always failed. Please see the detail as below:

```
dis chl(SERVER.C01)
27 : dis chl(SERVER.C01)
AMQ8414: 显示通道细节。
 CHANNEL(SERVER.C01)                     CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
 ALTDATE(2012-08-27)                     ALTTIME(16.05.40)
 COMPHDR(NONE)                           COMPMSG(NONE)
 DESCR( )                                HBINT(300)
 KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(999999999)
 MAXINSTC(999999999)                     MAXMSGL(4194304)
 MCAUSER( )                              MONCHL(QMGR)
 RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
 SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
 SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
 SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
 SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
 TRPTYPE(TCP)
dis chl(*) where(type lk SVRC*)
  28 : dis chl(*) where(chltype lk SVRC*)
 AMQ8569: 过滤器规范中的错误
 dis chl(*) where(chltype lk SVRC*

 AMQ8427: MQSC 命令的有效语法为：

 DISPLAY display_cmd
 WHERE( filter_keyword operator filter_value )

 operator := [ LT | GT | EQ | NE | LE | GE | CT | EX | LK | NL | CTG | EXG ]
```

In addition, how about `CT and EX`? Please help me out

```
WebSphere MQ
7.0.1.9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear whether you are having this problem with other object types but as for channels, filtering based on channel type is not allowed.  This is probably because selection by type has always been supported anyway.  Just specify `TYPE` or `CHLTYPE` in the display command:

```
dis chl(*) chltype(svrconn)
     1 : dis chl(*) chltype(svrconn)
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN)            CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN)             CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
dis chl(*) type(svrconn)
     2 : dis chl(*) type(svrconn)
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN)            CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN)             CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
```

The Infocenter page for [`DISPLAY CHANNEL`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/sc11770_.htm) states:

> Almost any parameter that can be used to display attributes for this
>   DISPLAY command. However, you cannot use the CMDSCOPE, QSGDISP, or
>   MCANAME parameters as filter keywords. You cannot use TYPE (or
>   CHLTYPE) if it is also used to select channels.

I'm not sure how you might use `TYPE` or `CHLTYPE` *other* than to select channels and I've requested a clarification made to the page to explain that.  In the meantime, be aware that selection on `TYPE` or `CHLTYPE` is not supported using the `WHERE` clause.  Were there cases other than channels where you had trouble with `LK` and `NK`?

**UPDATE**
Responding to the comment, two things to be aware of.  First, as per the Infocenter, "You cannot use a generic filter-value for parameters with numeric values or with one of a set of values."  This means, for example, that it is invalid to specify `DIS CHL(*) WHERE(MCATYPE LK P*)` because `MCATYPE` is specified by one of a set of values.  It can be only `PROCESS` or `THREAD`.  Nor would it be valid to specify `DIS CHL(*) WHERE(LONGTMR LK 1*)` because `LONGTMR` takes a numeric value.

The second item of interest is the syntax of the quoting in the `WHERE` clause.  Like all `MQSC` parameters, the `WHERE` clause folds unquoted values to UPPER CASE.  Since WebSphere MQ evaluates these in case-sensitive fashion, something like `DIS Q(*) WHERE(DESCR LK W*)` works because many of the queues have a description beginning with `WebSphere` and the upper case `W` matches.  However, `DIS Q(*) WHERE(DESCR LK We*)` fails because the lower case `e` is folded to upper case which then does not match the value in the description field.  What does work here is `DIS Q(*) WHERE(DESCR LK 'We*')` where the string specifier is single-quoted.

So the issues you are seeing may be due to use of the `LK` operator against a string value that is part of an enumeration, or possibly due to case sensitivity failing to match unquoted filter values.

The `CT` and `CTG` and their complements are the operators to use when the filter keyword is a list.  For example, in the `NAMELIST` object the attribute `NAMES` contains a list of values.  Something like `WHERE(NAMES LK SYS*)` would be ambiguous because `LK` operates on unary values.  So `CT` and `CTG` are provided as operators that work on sets.  A couple of examples to demonstrate this syntax would then be:

```
DIS NAMELIST(*) WHERE(NAMES CT SYSTEM.BROKER.DEFAULT.STREAM)
DIS NAMELIST(*) WHERE(NAMES CTG SYS*)
```

The first displays any `NAMELIST` objects where one of the entries in the `NAMES` attribute matches exactly.  The second allows a similar match based on a generic string prefix.  Be sure to quote if the expected value is in anything other than all UPPER CASE or if the value contains an embedded space.

Comment: uh....To be honest, i just wanna try use operator LK、NL、CT and EX. So i chose the attribute CHLTYPE randomly in above example, nothing special. Rob, can u give me some actual usage for operators LK and CT?

Comment: That's exactly what i need and your explanation is very clear. Thanks always Rob

Comment: Glad to help! Honestly, I learned something new researching this so the question is much appreciated. Had never used the CT or CTG before.